# Java 8 alternative to Map.entry() for mapping values to new Map?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I got a solution to a problem I've been trying to fix for a long time.
Unfortunately, I cannot use the solution since the target java version is Java 8.

```
Map<List<String>, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(List.of("Los Angeles", "New York", "Chicago"), "USA");
    map.put(List.of("Toronto", "Vancover", "Montréal"), "Canada");

    Map<String, String> newMap = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(entry -> entry.getKey()
            .stream()
            .map(city -> Map.entry(city, entry.getValue())))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

This would return me a Map like: `{New York=USA, Chicago=USA, Los Angeles=USA, Toronto=Canada}`

Now my question, can I arrive at this result without using Map.entry(...) in Java 8?

Comment: `city -> new java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(city, entry.getValue())`. If the lib is already on your class or module path, you can also use `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair.of(city, entry.getValue())`, which is more concise.

Comment: It is `Map.entrySet()`, not `Map.entry()`, and what make you think you need an alternative?

Comment: @user207421 [`Map.entry()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entry-K-V-) is a Java 9+ shortcut for creating an entry. It's not available in Java 8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
.map(city -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(city, entry.getValue())))
```

Comment: Closer to `Map.entry(…)` regarding functionality would `SimpleImmutableEntry` or even `new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(Objects.requireNonNull(city), Objects.requireNonNull(entry.getValue()))`. But if only brevity matters, `SimpleEntry` is obviously closer…