# Cannot resolve method 'entry' in 'Map'

Tags: java

I am using this class to manipulate some data using Java:

```
private static Set<Entry<String, String>> flatten(Map<String, List<String>> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream().flatMap(e ->
          e.getValue().stream().map(v -> Map.entry(e.getKey(), v))
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

However, when I try to compile on eclipse/intellij, I am getting this error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'entry' in 'Map'
```

As you can see on the code below, everything is working fine:
https://www.online-java.com/4LblEuqTN6

My code on eclipse is the following:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map.*;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="test")
public class HelloController extends BaseExtController {
    
    private static Set<Entry<String, String>> flatten(Map<String, List<String>> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream().flatMap(e ->
          e.getValue().stream().map(v -> Map.entry(e.getKey(), v))
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
    
    private static Map<String, List<String>> group(Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> entries) {
        return entries.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())
        ));
    }
    
    @RequestMapping (value="sync", method = RequestMethod.GET
            , produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Map<String, List<String>> syncForms(
                Model model,
                HttpServletRequest request, 
                HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        
        Map<String, List<String>> dictOP = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        Map<String, List<String>> dictMobile = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
       
        List<String> obj1Mobile = new ArrayList<String>();
       
        List<String> obj1Op = new ArrayList<String>();
       
        obj1Mobile.add("Argentina");

        obj1Op.add("Argentina");
       
        dictOP.put("obj1", obj1Op);
       
        dictMobile.put("obj1", obj1Mobile);
       
       
        Set<Entry<String, String>> mobileEntries = flatten(dictMobile);
        Set<Entry<String, String>> opEntries = flatten(dictOP);
        Set<Entry<String, String>> add = new HashSet<>(opEntries);
        add.removeAll(mobileEntries);
        Set<Entry<String, String>> remove = new HashSet<>(mobileEntries);
        remove.removeAll(opEntries);
       
        return group(add);
    }
```

Do you guys know why this is happening ? Am I defining some wrong type ?

Comment: [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) does not have an `entry()` method. What is this code intended to do?

Comment: `Map.entry()` was added in Java 9, are you by any chance compiling using Java 8?

Comment: Yes, i am using Java 8.

Comment: Well, then the method won't be available for you. Either upgrade your Java version or provide your own implementation of `Map.Entry` which you can map to (or use a library like Apache Commons Collections which should have a ready-to-use implementation).

Comment: Ok then, I will follow this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60316828/java-8-alternative-to-map-entry-for-mapping-values-to-new-map